# How can my UIViewController know who put it on the stack?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

This is for an addition to a legacy iPhone app with the architecture already defined (years ago, by somebody else.)

The main limitation is that the functionality of the main menu system is based on configuration files, so I can't call any specific initialisation code from the main menu.

This means that the view I am developing is stand-alone, and has to somehow manage its states with the information from the system.

Further, on each screen there is a "Settings" button, taking the user to a Settings pane, that is pushed on the navigation stack on top of "my" view. When the user closes the settings pane, my view reappears, as per normal navigation.

OK, so here is my problem:

When the user enters my view from the menu I want it to be reset so all input fields are empty.

If the user goes to the settings screen and returns to my screen, I want all previous input to be preserved, i.e., not reset to empty fields.

If the user then goes back to the main menu, and re-enters my screen, fields should be empty again.

Is there a robust, documented and preferably simple way to know if I should reset the fields in this scenario?

Comment: "legacy iPhone app"...man I'm getting old...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check the navigation stack to see if the settings page is currently on the stack?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)aAnimated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:aAnimated];

    NSArray* stack = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];

    UIViewController* last = [stack lastObject];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the settings controller has already been popped off the stack at that point (just tried it), so no dice. Pity, it would have been nice, simple and robust.

Comment: The idea of using [[self navigationController] viewControllers] to peek into the stack is really useful - I only had to put it in viewDidDisappear to get some useful information out of it. The useful information is: 1) There is a stack, and 2) the top item has just been pushed onto it from somewhere. This is different from being popped off the stack, because when this method is called, the self.navigationController is nil.

Comment: With thanks to Daniel R Hicks for identifying the event handler to use, this method seems to provide the information I need, albeit in a slightly backwards fashion. Thanks to everyone for your ideas!

Comment: Of course, not every application uses a navigation controller.

Comment: @HotLicks of course, not every application doesn't use a navigation controller ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably viewDidDisappear is called when your view is hidden for some reason.  You could presumably get the UIWindow and work up the view chain to find where your view is in the chain (if it is at all) and what is hiding it.

Non-trivial, though, and the sort of thing that will likely need to be "maze bright" vs robust.

(Though if a navigation controller is consistently used it becomes much simpler.)

Comment: This method (viewDidDisappear) is the winner among the events to use - thanks for pointing it out. See Sam's answer for a simple way to get to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

In the view controller in question, how about you set up a delegate.

```
id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```

for the header, then synthesize in the implementation.

Whenever you push to this view controller, set `self` as the delegate from the pushing view.  Then in this view controller, you can perform a check in the `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear:` (or wherever you feel it would be necessary) with something like the following:

```
if ([self.delegate isKindOfClass:[SomeClass class]]) {
    // now you can find which class sent to this view;
}
```

That should do the trick, so I hope it helps you out

EDIT: considering you are switching views without always using a nav controller, the above won't be valid all the time.  In that case, you are probably better off using an internal property as well as an outlet to your settings pane.  So in this view controller, you'll want something like this in the header:

```
BOOL shouldReset;
@property (readwrite) BOOL shouldReset;
```

In your `viewDidLoad`, you'll want to initialize this as `shouldReset = YES`.  You should also put this in your `viewDidDisappear:` since it is your default behavior.  When you present the settings pane, give the settings an outlet to the current view controller so you can, from within the settings (when you press the back button) set `[self.otherViewController setShouldReset:NO]`.  Then in your `viewDidAppear:` for the original view controller in question, you can check to see if it should reset its fields or not

Comment: Not a bad idea, but would it not require that I modify the code handling the main menu, not to mention the system-provided navigation controller that handles the "back" button from the settings pane?

Comment: It shouldn't, no.  All this would really do is give you an outlet to where you just came from...wait a second, you aren't switching to the view via pushing/popping all the time, so this won't always work.  I'm going to edit the response to something that fits your need better.  Sorry about that

Comment: No, my problem is that it is not "me", as in my code, that pushes the view on the stack, so I can't set the delegate. I only have my own UIViewController's events and whatever I can get from the system (such as the UIApplication). Unless I want to make changes to the original code, but I'd rather not - because then there is a real risk that it suddenly becomes my code, with all that that entails.